# Hacer que una funcion devuelva un objeto implementado c++

Tags: c++, funciones, clase, object

Tengo una clase creada y que funciona correctamente, en este caso es una Cola, con sus atributos y funciones.
Ahora quiero crear e invocar una funcion que devuelva un objeto de este tipo pero me lanza una excepcion. Tengo:

```
Cola trocear(char[] palabra){
    Cola cola1;
    //resto del codigo
    return cola1
}

main(){
    char palabra[]="hola";
    Cola c;
    c=trocear(palabra);
}
```

Las lineas de codigo estan bien, lo unico que me falla es el momento de realizar la invocacion

Comment: ¿ Podrías mostrar el código de tu destructor y del constructor de movimiento ? O el del constructor copia, si no has implementado el del movimiento.

Comment: "*me lanza una excepción*" ¿Qué excepción te lanza?